# an inequality with a cyclic shift of exponents

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove that
$$
x_1^{x_1}+x_2^{x_2}+\ldots+x_n^{x_n}\ge x_1^{x_2}+x_2^{x_3}+\ldots+x_n^{x_1}
$$
for any $x_1,\dots,x_n>0$.

I found this problem in a contest-preparing ebook. There was a solution I wasn't able to understand, it required some results from multivariable calculus. I was trying to solve it with less advanced stuff, but with no sensible result to show.

Comment: I think we can just use greedy theorem. Raise the greatest number to the greatest power and so on.

Comment: I have a proof for $n=2$ and $n=3.$ :(

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is this for $n = 2$?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226202/prove-that-aabb-ge-abba1-if-a-b-0

Comment: @River Li Yes, but this proof is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Whatever, $n = 2$ is easy.

Comment: @River Li   Not so easy, but it's smooth enough. A proof for $n=3$ is not so easy already. For $n=4$ I have no a proof.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325361/prove-the-inequality-x-1y-1x-2y-2-cdotsx-ny-n-geq-x-1y-pi1?noredirect=1